# Google Drive listing, searching and deleting files

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm building a web app that integrates with Google Drive, and am wondering if there was a way to list, search or delete files.

I see from https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files#resource that there are 4 operations. If there are no list and search capabilities then the onus is on the app to handle the management of file ids.

Is there another API I should be using? Are those features in the works?

Comment: My reading would be that the Google Drive API is focusing on managing one file, like a text editor would do. Deleting, listing & searching is up to Google Drive itself. If you don't want that you might consider the Documents List API and not integrating into the Drive UI (but still integrating into the Drive content)

Comment: @HelmuthB is correct in his comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/) was launched *yesterday*, which now supports full file operations including listing, searching, etc.

Check out the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss for how to do a search using Java... the java sample code for files().list() just prints a list of every file (which, by the way, took 50 minutes to list ~2300 files... is it supposed to take that long?) - it doesn't really show how I could get a filtered list using Java. Edit: Nevermind, found it (I think, haven't tested yet.) My code looks like this: drive.files().list().setQ("q as explained").execute();